# How to apply Null-Conditional Operator on blank strings?

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have a string value and need to convert that to decimal.

```
var str = null;           
decimal number;
decimal d = Decimal.TryParse(str, out number) ? number : 0M;
```

It's working fine.

Now I am trying to achieve the same thing by using the new  [Null-Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) of C# 6.0 . How can I do so?

I know it's a wrong attempt.

```
 var str = null;
 decimal d = str?.Convert.ToDecimal(str);
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. An empty string isn't `null`.

Comment: ok.. now i have set the value as null.in that case how should i proceed?

Comment: It's behavior change. `Decimal.TryParse` doesn't throw FormatException, `Convert.ToDecimal` does. How would you handle that? Null-Conditional operator doesn't help here.

Comment: What if `str` is "abc"? `TryParse` will just return false (and set `number` to `0M` (`default(decimal)`)), `Convert` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) you can't do that as null conditional operator is:

> Used to test for null before performing a member access (?.) or index
>   (?[) operation

and in this case you aren't indexing or accessing the input string members.

As the other answer stated the way to do that would be

```
decimal d = String.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? default(decimal) : Convert.ToDecimal(str);
```

Answer (score 5):

A *blank* (empty) string is not `null`, so you can't use that operator.

You could do:

```
decimal d = string.IsNullOrEmpty(str) ? 0M : Convert.ToDecimal(str);
```

---

**EDIT**: OK, now we're starting with a `null` string. In which case...

```
decimal d = (str == null) ? 0M : Convert.ToDecimal(str);
```

I still don't think that this is an appropriate time to use the null-conditional operator, because that's most useful when the ultimate result of the expression can be null - which is not true in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answering the question, but I would create an extension method where you have the advantage of being able to formally call it on `null` values too.

This implementation gives the correct `double` if the input string is in a valid format (using the default formatting), and gives the optionally passed default value if string is null or empty or is in incorrect format.

```
public static double ConvertToDoubleOrDefault(this string input, double def = 0.0) 
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) return def;
  double result;
  if (!double.TryParse(str, out result)) return def;
  return result; 
}

....

string test = "1234";
string test2 = null;
var d = test.ConvertToDoubleOrDefault(); // => 1234
d = test2.ConvertToDoubleOrDefault(); // => 0.0
```